# MySQL: how to find tables with column(s) that has Extra on update current_timestamp()?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mariadb

I am working on MariaDB V10.6, and just realized the following extra feature has been automatically added to a timestamp column in a table that I am working on.

```
on update current_timestamp()
```

With some help from Google, I was able to remove this unwanted extra from this table.

My question is, is there a way I can find all the table in the database that has this extra and remove them if they are not desired? Some sort of query that I can run against schema?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW this is documented behaviour https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behaviour https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/ ,to find

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOURSCHEMA' AND EXTRA ='on update current_timestamp()';
```

To modify

```
alter table T modify column yourcolumn timestamp default 0;
```

But do you really want such a default? And is timestamp a suitable datatype for your purposes?

https://dbfiddle.uk/lnPEBnXq

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I actually did this long time ago but somehow cannot recall or find it by Google. 
To answer your question, yes timestamp with null as default is suitable for my application. A null for the end of time range will mean it is open ended. I find it is better than to use some arbitrary time from the distant future.